# A better way to re-use a boilerplate search parameter across controller actions

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

How do I re-use boilerplate query code across multiple controller actions in CakePHP 2.4?

I've got some join code I need to re-use across multiple actions, which excludes all Posts which belong to a Project where `Project.published = 0` from my `find()`. I've done this by creating a public class array to hold the query code.

This works, however I'd like to add some additional parameters based on variables- specifically, allowing the owner of a `Project` to see data belonging to their project, even if it's unpublished.

If the array were integrated as part of the controller action, I'd simply add `'ProjectAlias.user_id' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id")` to the final `OR` array below. However, I can't include that as part of a class array, and I need to create it in the action, as seen below.

This doesn't feel especially elegant. **Is there a cleaner / more Cake way to handle this?**

My current code:

```
//==============
// ADDITIONAL JOIN TO RESTRICT RESULTS TO LIVE PROJECTS
//================
public $joins = array( 
    array(
        'table' => 'projects',
        'alias' => 'ProjectAlias',
        'type' => 'right',
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(  // One of these two things:
                'Post.project_id' => null, // Posts with no project
                'AND' => array( // And posts with a Project that is published.
                    'Post.project_id = ProjectAlias.id',
                    'OR' => array(
                        'ProjectAlias.published !=' => 0,
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    )
);
//===============
// Example function showing how this array is used. There are four in all
// so repeating the above code would get to be too much.
//================
public function example() { 

    // Let project leads see data from their hidden projects, by modifying the array.
    // This doesn't seem very elegant!

    $this->joins[0]['conditions']['OR']['AND']['OR'][] = array(
        'ProjectAlias.user_id' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id")
    );

    // Use the array
    $this->paginator->settings['joins'] = $joins;

    $this->set('posts', $this->Paginator->paginate());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you can create a function which requires arguments in AppController which returns the join array & call it from any actions of any controllers. Now, regarding different params for different cases, first you can use-

```
$this->request->action
```

to get the current action (or controller as well if needed).
Now, you can set an associative array or if else block in the function in AppController to define the join array, using function arguments as required. Then you can get custom made $joins array from any actions.